# Friend methods in hierarchical structures using C++

Tags: c++11, friend

I am currently implementing some sort of hierarchical structure and I need to assign the parent entity to the child if the child is attached to the parent. My question is, if I could solve this problem using a `friend` method in the parent class and if this would be good coding style. Here is a short example to explain what I mean:

```
class Node {
   Node* parent;

   Node() : parent(nullptr) { }

   friend void attachChild(const Node& child) const;
   friend void detachChild(unsigned long idx) const;
};

class ListNode : public Node {
   std::vector<Node*> childs;

   ListNode() : Node() { this->childs = {}; }

   void attachChild(Node* child) const {
      child->parent = this;
      childs.push_back(child);
   }

   void detachChild(unsigned long idx) const {
      child->parent = nullptr;
      child.erase(child.begin() + idx)
   }
};

class NodeOne : public Node {};
class NodeTwo : public Node {};
class NodeThree : public Node {};
```

And a last short comment: A child entity could obviously just have one parent entity, whereas the child and parent could be in my scenario of the same type.

Comment: Using `friend` is seldom a good choice, it's often a sign of bad design. Though there are cases where it's hard to to not use it, but in your case it might be better to have setter/getter functions. Unless if the `Node` class can be a private internal class inside the `Parent` class, then using `friend` could be an okay solution.

Comment: Node and parent always depend on the same base class and both could have a parent (updated the example). Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

**YES**, in this case it is bad coding style. Typically for heirarchical structures like this, the information about parent/child relationships is kept in the node itself.

The `ListNode` class is redundant, and it's functionality really belongs to the node itself, which is why you find yourself needing to friend the class.

You can avoid using friend functions by simply adding a `setParent` method to the node class. If you want to make sure only nodes can mess around with parent/child relationships, make it private/protected.

```
class Node {

public:

    Node() : parent(nullptr) { };

    int addChild(Node* child)
    {
        child->setParent(this);
        this->children.push_back(child);

        int idx = this->children.size() - 1;
        return idx;
    };
    void removeChild(unsigned long idx)
    {
        Node* child = children.at(idx);
        child->setParent(nullptr);
        this->children.erase(children.begin() + idx);
    }

private:

    void setParent(Node* node)
    {
        parent = node;
    }

private:

    Node* parent;
    std::vector<Node*> children;
};
```

example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Node parent;
    Node child;
    parent.addChild(&child);
}
```